# How to add total row in SQL Server where the query contains case function

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum, case

Below is my query and the resulting columns but don't know how to add a query to get a total column.

```
Select  
    case PlacementVerificationmethod 
       when 107 then 'contact center'
       when 1 then 'work number/3rd party verification'
       when 101 then 'Placement call'
       when 102 then 'walk in/Self report'
       when 103 then 'Email'
       when 104 then 'Employer Report'
       when 105 then 'In person with participant'
       when 106 then 'In person with employer'
       else 'unknown'
    end  as 'Placement method', 
    count(*) as 'Total Placement' 
from
    AssessEmploymentPlacement
group by  
    PlacementVerificationMethod
```

Result:

```
In person with employer              145
Placement call                     13813
work number/3rd party verification  3492
Employer Report                     4463
In person with participant           168
unknown                            61387
walk in/Self report                 2227
Email                                115
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a total *column*, then you can do:

```
Select (case PlacementVerificationmethod 
            when  107 then 'contact center'
            when 1 then 'work number/3rd party verification'
            when 101 then 'Placement call'
            when 102  then 'walk in/Self report'
            when 103 then 'Email'
            when 104 then 'Employer Report'
            when 105 then 'In person with participant'
            when 106 then 'In person with employer'
            else 'unknown'
        end) as [Placement method],
       count(*) as [Total Placement],
       sum(count(*)) over () as Total
from AssessEmploymentPlacement
group by PlacementVerificationMethod;
```

If you want another *row* with the total, then use grouping sets or rollup:

```
group by grouping sets ((PlacementVerificationMethod), ())
```